# EF, and why do I have to restart the web site instead of just recycling the app pool?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have this code in my EF's OnModelCreating() method. It detects whether a table has a column, then binds the right class to EF based on that.

```
  if (new ColumnDetector().AdminColumnExists())
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithAdmin>();
  }
  else
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithoutAdmin>();
  }
```

Initially, the column didn't exist. Then later it was added to the table. The above code doesn't detect it because it already ran. I thought recycling the app pool would do it, but it didn't. Does that make sense? Shouldn't this code run again? I had to restart the web site to get this code to detect the column and set the right class again. Why wouldn't recycling the app pool be enough?

Comment: How is your DbContext is created? Sounds like it is a singleton

Comment: Should that make a difference? If the app pool is reset, shouldn't the app basically restart?

Comment: Recycling the appPool is not the same as restarting it. If anything is keeping the appPool alive, new requests would be loaded into a new appPool and the former one would be stopped once nothing keep it alive. If you want to make sure, in your log, add a line when with a `guid` to identify which instance of the appPool receives your 2nd request (in which you say the column now exists)

Comment: Does recycling an app pool cause the app to restart? I thought it did. If not, then that would explain the issue.

Comment: It makes sense that recycling the app pool didn't work. When a recycle is done, a new worker process starts and new requests are directed to it. This happens before the current process is stopped. That allows no disruption. It also means that our application just keeps running in the same state as it did before.